# Merge the "3g" and "3g-internet" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

- [3g](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3g) — 34 tagged, 9 this year

  > 3G - when used as a single word - stands for the third generation of cellular wireless standards.
- [3g-internet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3g-internet) — 19 tagged, 1 this year

  > *no tag wiki/excerpt*

Whilst I understand that the internet is a subset of 3G, questions tagged with [3g-internet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3g-internet) have either also been tagged with [3g](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3g) or refer to 3G in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done - this was an easy merge / synonym to convert them all to [cellular-data](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-data) with any further cleanup by retagging questions that were erroneously tagged as either 3g tag.